# Usage and Benefits of Last Activity Storage - Session Management

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, security, database-design

I have been seeing examples and documentations of various frameworks about last activity storage into database instead of session arrays (temporarily). After researching on various websites, blogs and tuts site what I learned a single common approach on why to keep track of last activity is that we can inspect when the user last logged out/in.

==========

## Questions

a. What would be those major reasons and benefits for storing user's last activity?
b. What are the advantages and disadvantages of storing user's last activity into database instead of storing them into temporary session arrays?
c. What are those best strategies you use for security purposes by using user's last activity?
d. Is there any way better than last activity storage for keeping track of users and for enhancing web application security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а) It depends on the needs of the application you are building. For some scenarios it is irrelevant, and for some it is important (when was the last time a customer logged in in your e-commerce store?)

b) storage in DB - global access to the session activity, meaning you can display that to all/other users than the one that is currently logged in. Storing in DB means larger database space so you will need trashing mechanism (Codeigniter does this automatically I believe)

c) If you store the session onto the server, it depends on the security of the server, and if you store it in the database, it depends on the security level of the database. In any case, the cookie containing the session key should be random, long string (handled by Codeigniter as well). Personally, I have used both approaches, depending on the needs of th application.

d) Again this depends on the scenario. For example, if you see that the user has not logged in for more than a year, and there are 5 consecutive unsuccessful attempts to log in, it probably means that he has forgotten his password, so you should send him an email containing a reset link or a warning that there were attempts for logging in.

Comment: Glad you helped :) Well, Thanks for the detailed and meaningful answer. :) Can you answer me one thing more. How can I track how many times a specific user visited a specific link on my site? For example, If he click contact-us.php link 5 times, how can I know this?

Comment: Great, well if you store the session in the DB, every time the user clicks on it, you will add to your session_data an attribute contact_us_visits_count and you will increment it. Or if you start a session when the user is logged in (with username and password, you can get even into more details - you will be able to determine which user visited which page how many times). Then you can build reports based on this data. You can also combine that with Google Analytics data for even more details about visitor behavior.